# Build error with Xcode 6 and iPhone 6 and iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, arm64

I am having some build issues with Xcode 6 and cannot get my app to compile for all devices and  simulators at the same time. The issue seems to be related to figuring out the Valid Architectures settings in the build settings, partially explained in other SO threads, but not sufficiently addressing my specific problem.

I am building a Cordova 3.6 app, and working on a MBP Mac OS X 10.9, with Xcode 6.

With the following Build Settings (screenshot below), I get the following build results:

- Build successful - Simulator - iPhone 4s/iPhone 5s/iPhone 6
- Build successful - Devices - iPhone 4s (iPhone 5s device not tested)
- Build FAILS      - Devices - iPhone 6

My build settings and error for building for the above results are as follows:

[image: Build Settings]

[image: Error]

However, if I change the **Valid Architectures** and remove "arm64", and change **Build Active Architecture Only** to "No", then my build works for all devices but fails for simulators for iPhone 5s and iPhone 6. I get the following build results:

- Build successful - Simulator - iPhone 4s
- Build FAILS      - Simulator - iPhone 5s / iPhone 6
- Build successful - Devices - iPhone 4s / iPhone 6 (iPhone 5s device not tested)

I have the following questions:

1. Can someone explain what's going on? How can removing "arm64" actually allow me to build for  iPhone 6 device?
2. What can I do to make sure I can run on ALL simulators AND devices?
3. Should I even bother about making it run on all simulators and devices? This is my first pending submission to the App store, so I'm not sure what I need to be successfully building for. If I can build successfully for iPhone 4s and iPhone 6 devices, do I need to worry about getting them to work on each simulator perfectly?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. While I don't know exactly how to address the above issues, I just did a platform update for cordova, and did a clean build. Now I can build and run on all simulators and devices. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I have same issue. Cannot build for iPhone5s, 6, 6 plus. I use cordove verion 3.5.0. Which version did you used? 3.6.0-0.2.8 Do you think this is a Cordove version problem?

Comment: Hey Wen, I'm not sure if you figured this out, but I did a Cordova version update, which took me from 3.5 (I think) to 3.6, then did a full clean build from there. So, yes, it appears to be an issue with Cordova 3.5. Good luck!